# Arch Linux PV Template for Citrix Xenserver

Tags: arch-linux, xen

I'm looking for an Arch Linux PV template for Citrix Xenserver 6.2. The problem is that my infrastructure doesn't support HVM, so the usual route of bare install and then configure isn't an option here...

Answer (score 0):

You can use these instructions to make your own Arch Linux PV template.

https://github.com/uncon/wiki/blob/master/xenserver/arch_template.md

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.